# How to make a Unique id for a dragged item when copied from a draglist to another draglist in angular material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I am having a problem with my drag list and the problem is that when I drag and copy each item all of them are the same. I want to have the same structure of the object but with a different id so it can be unique and I have been having a problem with doing that. Can Someone help me, please?

```
    makeString(): string {
    let outString: string = '';
    let inOptions: string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {

      outString += inOptions.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * inOptions.length));

    }

    return outString;
  }

  result: string = this.makeString();

      drop1(event: any) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      copyArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
      this.taskstodo[event.previousIndex].id = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 15).toString() + this.makeString();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which was to transfer the item from the first droplist to the other and then push the transferred item back to the fist droplist's array and for the first drop list and the second drop-list I added another list and then connected those lists after the transfer from those lists was finished and I added two actions for my copy of the first drop list so that after the transfer the first list wouldn't change and stay the same.

```
  drop1(event: any) {
console.log(event.item.nameid)

if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
  moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
} else {
  let index1 = event.previousIndex
  let index2 = event.currentIndex
  this.dragables2[0] = this.action1()
  this.dragables2[1] = this.action2()
  transferArrayItem(
    this.dragables2,
    this.lists2,
    index1,
    index2);
  console.log(this.lists2[0])
  this.dragables2 = [];
  for (let item of this.lists2) {
    this.dragables2.push(item)
  }
  this.taskstodo = this.lists2
  console.log(this.lists2)
  console.log(this.dragables2)
  // transfer complete so copy object back

}
```

}

```
 action1() {
let json = {object : {type: 'item1' , nameid: '1414'}}
json['object']['type'] = 'item1'
json['object']['nameid'] = Math.random().toString()
return json
```

}

```
    action2() {
let json = {object : {type: 'item2' , nameid: '1212'}}
json['object']['type'] = 'item2'
json['object']['nameid'] = Math.random().toString()
return json
```

}